# "The UserID did not identify a User in the system." while sending document Using Docusign rest API

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to send the document from API, it raises "The UserID did not identify a User in the system." Error, we have checked all the users and their permission sets in production account, we didn't find anything. Could you please guide me on it. #DocuSignAPI

Comment: When you say "didn't find anything" do you mean that you found the userid you are sending and it had valid permissions? Someone may be confused by this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Next time you have a question, please include more information on what you tried that did not work. For example, what authentication method are you using? Show us the code that raised the error. Etc.

Comment: are you using Demo environment userId while connecting with PROD DS Account?

Answer (score 0):

What software are you using?

I suggest that you start with a working code example and then go on from there.

See:

- C# -- https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core
- PHP – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant
- Java – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant
- Node.js – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant
- Python – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant
- Ruby – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-ruby-auth-code-grant
- Curl (direct API) – https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-curl